# Число сочетаний (с из n по k) есть ли быстрый алгоритм? Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, производительность

Число сочетаний можно найти используя рекурсию и, соответственно, рекуррентное соотношение. Код получается вот такой:

```
def C(n, k):
    if k == n or k == 0:
        return 1
    if k != 1:
        return C(n-1, k) + C(n-1, k-1)
    else:
        return n


print(C(int(input()), int(input())))
```

Но я знаю, что рекурсия штука не быстрая и не всегда надежная. Есть ли другие алгоритмы и на сколько они быстрые?

Comment: Число сочетаний можно как бы найти и без рекурсии, используя прямую формулу... особенно если есть готовый оператор вычисления факториала или таблица факториалов. В крайнем случае - один цикл.

Comment: В школе же формулу проходят?

Comment: `n! / (k! (n - k)!)`. Факториал реализован в функции `math.factorial`. Ваш алгоритм не оптимален, но не потому, то рекурсия медленная, а потому, что результаты не кешируются. `@functools.lru_cache(None)` значительно ускорит программу.

Comment: @andreymal, это конечно да, но там факториалы, считать которые совсем не хочется, это тоже не быстро

Comment: @AntivistHome подозреваю, что всяко быстрее рекурсии :)

Comment: Самое быстрое — воспользоваться математической библиотекой, например, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025162/statistics-combinations-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через факториал медленно и не эффективно.
В формуле `n! / (k! (n - k)!)`, если сократить, то получится `(n-k+1)(n-k+2)..n/k!`

*Получается такой код:*

```py
def С(n, k):
    if 0 <= k <= n:
        nn = 1
        kk = 1
        for t in xrange(1, min(k, n - k) + 1):
            nn *= n
            kk *= t
            n -= 1
        return nn // kk
    else:
        return 0
```

Также можно посмотреть библиотеку [`itertools`](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-itertools.html):

```py
combinations('ABCD', 2)  # AB AC AD BC BD CD
```

Answer (score 4):

используйте `math.comb`

```
import math

n = int(input())
k = int(input())

print(math.comb(n, k))
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать модуль `itertools`, там сразу реализована нужная операция. Она составляет необходимые сочетания. Подсчитать их кол-во не составит труда.

```py
import itertools

def C(n, k):
    return len(list(itertools.combinations(range(1, n), k)))
```

Хочу заметить, что сочетания она может составлять из чего угодно (т.е. передавать можно любой итерируемый контейнер).

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html

Comment: @0andriy Почему не вынесли в ответ?

Comment: @V-Mor Генерировать сочетания, чтобы узнать их количество - неразумно, т.к. существуют простые формулы

Comment: место `len(list(...))` лучше писать `sum(1 for _ in ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Для ТС уже неактуально, наверное, но может кому пригодится.

Треугольник Паскаля (сочетания - это биномиальные коэффициенты).

Чтобы его "нарисовать", умножать вообще не нужно.

Быстрее уже никак.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Вася Злой Однако вычисление элемента треугольника Паскаля требует **квадратичного** числа операций, а можно обойтись линейным.

Comment: @MBo
Не такое уже и квадратичное. )
Для вычисления всех (!) элементов n-ой строки нужно меньше чем Sum(1, 2, ..., n) сложений.

Comment: @Вася Злой Для заполнения треугольника до n-й строчки включительно нужно `(n-1)(n-2)/2` сложений - это вполне себе квадратично

Comment: @MBo
Меньше.
Я не допечатал, случайно на энтер нажал.
Т.к. треугольник симметричный, то Для заполнения треугольника до n-й строчки включительно нужно Sum([2/2], [3/2], ... [n/2]) 
И то это в случае, если заполнять треугольник классич. методом.

Comment: Например, при классическом методе для нахождения 10 строчки нужно 25 сложений, а если заполнять диагоналями, то можно и в 16 вписаться.
Ну, если не считать инкремент в цикле за сложение.

Comment: @Вася Злой И в результате получаем.... всё равно квадратичную формулу.